# How do I obtain the client's IPv6 address in the Akka/Spray framework?

Tags: scala, akka, ipv6, spray, ipv4

I am currently using the below code to get the IPv4 address:

```
import spray.http.RemoteAddress
...
val ipV4: String = remoteAddress.toOption.map(_.getHostAddress).getOrElse("<unknown>")
```

However, I cannot seem to find any information on doing the same thing for IPv6. Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: According to the documentation, `RemoteAddress.toOption` wraps a `java.net.InetAddress` which is an abstract class extended by both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.  Your current code should work just fine either way, assuming that `remoteAddress` has an IPv6 address.

Comment: @IanMcLaird Ah. Okay. So, then how do I obtain an IPv6 version of the remote address (as opposed to the IPv4 currently being supplied)?

Comment: Run the code on a machine that can only be hit through IPv6.  You don't need a code change.  You'll get the address the remote machine connected from.  It can only connect to you from one address at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not depend from your method - it depends from the configuration of your network.

[Look at the source code](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-http/src/main/scala/spray/http/RemoteAddress.scala) of `spray.http.RemoteAddress`:

```
def apply(bytes: Array[Byte]): RemoteAddress = {
    require(bytes.length == 4 || bytes.length == 16)
    try IP(InetAddress.getByAddress(bytes)) catch { case _: UnknownHostException ⇒ Unknown }
}
```

This code wraps both IPv4 (4 byte) and IPv6 (16 byte). As a result you will receive IPv4 address, IPv6 address or special Pv4-mapped-to-IPv6 address depends from your network settings.

Try to run your code on the local pc where network interface configured to use IPv6 and you will see.

This is the object that you actually receive from Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html

Comment: I'm not sure this answers my question. Your answer implies my code is receiving an IPv4 instance of InetAddress. So, how do I get an IPv6 instance of InetAddress from the Akka/Spray framework?

Comment: The same way. It is not depend from your metod - it depends ftom the configuration of your network. Try to run your code on the local pc where network interface configured to use ipv6 and you will see.

Comment: If you will update your answer including what you just said in your comment, I will accept it. And tysvm for creating the answer.